# Set index as number in template Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

Is it possible to set index in Angular 2 in template?
Let's say, I have

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    {{i}}. {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

And it displays 
0. First
1. Second
2. Third

And I would like to have
1. First
2. Second
3. Third

So, I would like to start with index 1.

I thought it could be achieved with one-way-building, but it doesn't work this way 
Here is plnkr [Example](https://embed.plnkr.co/0s3qtC0TvHdiJLmz4H3m/)

Answer (score 4):

did you try

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index + 1">
```

or

```
{{i + 1}}
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/4jqrvvDzv33wgROwncmg?p=preview

Comment: thank you, first i tried - doesn't work, but second works well :)